# Improving my database design using TPH Inheritance

Tags: c#, sql, database, database-design, table-per-hierarchy

This is my current database design, for the moment just look the student, teacher and classes tables.

[image]

I'm trying to convert some tables into news using TPH Inheritance. For example.

Create a new table called Person where contains:

- Id,
- FullName,
- EnrollmentDate (for student),
- Email (for student),
- HireDate (for teacher)

But is there remaining one field called `ClassId`, where it's contained in `Student` table. At this momment I don't know if should I create a join table to store the `ClassId` and `PersonId`, or just put the `ClassId` into the `Person` table. That's my big doubt.

Where do I have to put the `ClassId` field?

I have to mention that each student can only be in one class, not many. Teachers can have many classes as they want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't model the domain correctly:

First you must have students regardless of that they have class or not,
In current model, it seems that Student is a weak entity and depends on classes.

Courses are also independent of semester classes which might happen this year and don't happen next year.

But if you want to have TPH strategy to model the database this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) might be of help to you.

You will have a Person table, then Teacher table which has a reference to Person, and Student which also has a reference to Person table.
And at last, the student table has a reference to semester courses through a joint table.

Comment: So, (Students & Teachers is one table called Person) and Classes (or courses) should be independent tables. Dependent tables would be CourseIntructor (for teachers) and Enrollment for students as Join tables. What do you think?

Comment: Take a look at this link: file:///Users/jani/Downloads/ER%20Model%20for%20the%20University%20Database.doc, If you do a search on google you'll find more samples.